# Appending new row to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv of the form:

```
name,age,country  
john,23,japan  
mel,27,ireland
```

When I try to append with the following code:

```
import csv
info=['kirsty','32','germany']
with open('data.csv','a') as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(info)

file.close()
```

I get this on opening the file in notepad:

```
name,age,country  
john,23,japan   
mel,27,irelandkirsty,32,germany
```

I dont understand why the new entry isn't appending to the next line.

Comment: Probably the original file is missing a final newline `\n`.

Comment: Agreed. So something like `writer.writerow("\n")` before you write the info

Comment: I've tried that and the quotes around `\n` also show up in the new csv.

Comment: Are we really discussing how to add a newline to the file now? Just add `file.write('\n')`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey That actually has solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add *"\n"* before each new line.